# NServiceBus - configuring AzureStorageQueueTransport with Router (requires an explicitly defined serializer but I cannot do such)

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I'm trying to setup a Router to route messages from an Azure Storage Queue Transport to a RabbitMQ transport. I'm able to configure the RabbitMQ interface & connect just fine. However, when I try to start the router I get an error from NServiceBus stating "Use 'endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization();' to select a serializer." This is related to my `AzureStorageQueueTransport` interface registration. According to the NServiceBus docs, AzureStorageQueueTransports require an explicitly defined serializer (https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-storage-queues/). However, the pre-defined object given to me in the lambda doesn't appear to have a way to achieve this (it's of type `TransportExtensions<AzureStorageQueueTransport>`):

```
routerConfig.AddInterface<AzureStorageQueueTransport>("AzureStorageQueue", t =>
{
    t.ConnectionString(_settings.CloudBusSettings.TransportConnectionString);
    t.SerializeMessageWrapperWith<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
});
```

The method `SerializeMessageWrapperWith<>();` is the only configurable serialization setting I can find. It fails to start with the same error message above with or without this function call. I cannot find any example that uses AzureStorageQueueTransport with a router. I'm not sure how to fix this. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a NuGet versioning issues. I was originally using NServiceBus 7.2.0 with NServiceBus.Router & NServiceBus.Router.Connector versions 3.7.1.

Once I upgraded NServiceBus.Router & NServiceBus.Router.Connector to their latest versions (3.10.0 at the time of writing this) - this also required use of NServiceBus >= 7.4.0, I was able to start the router without error.

Not sure why it mattered as my original setup was all compatible, but it works